# in jquery ui dialog, how can i change the color / contract behind a single modal dialogs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

using [the jquery ui modal dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal), the background shades grey (i assuming this is being driven by my theme roller).  For one specific modal dialog i want the background to be darker than what i am getting by default with the default options.

More importantly, how can i change the shading on the background screen when i load one specific dialog.  In this case, I DON'T want to change the css of my theme roller css as i only want this to apply to one specific page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you place the following in your special page : thus overriding the the background

```
<style>
 .ui-widget-overlay {
      background: url("images/ui-bg_flat_0_aaaaaa_40x100.png") repeat-x scroll 50% 50% #AAAAAA;
       opacity: 0.3;
  }
</style>
```

Just adjust the opacity to the level you want and for IE you might need modify the image as well..

Hope i understand you...

Comment: `<style>` works better with CSS than `<script>` does in my experience. Also, you may need to specify `!important` as the theme CSS may be more specific than this.

Comment: Helped. Thank you. For some reason, I had to add position: absolute and top: 0 and left: 0