# How to change the back color of jquery ui dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I got now a Jquery ui dialog,it's content background is white, I want to make the background around it black with low opacity as facebook for example.In this picture shows a dialog box with a low opacity black background so how can I make this in jquery ui

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [in jquery ui dialog, how can i change the color / contract behind a single modal dialogs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449100/)

Comment: @Mathletics I tried this but nothing happened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
.ui-dialog, .ui-dialog, .ui-widget, .ui-widget-content,
.ui-corner-all, .foo{
    background: #ff0000; /*color sample*/
}​
```

**Update**

First edit your dialog script with :

```
open: function() {
    $('.ui-widget-overlay').addClass('custom-overlay');
},
close: function() {
    $('.ui-widget-overlay').removeClass('custom-overlay');
}
```

Then, you've to add css like :

```
.ui-widget-overlay.custom-overlay
{
   background-color: black;
   background-image: none;
   opacity: 0.9;
   z-index: 1040;    
}
```

I hope this worked.

**FINAL UPDATE**

This is worked fine ;)

http://jsfiddle.net/aldiunanto/G8RQS/3/

Comment: You misunderstood me, I don't mean to change the content background but I mean to change the back of the content you can see this image
http://i.stack.imgur.com/cPrsn.png

Comment: @KevinMartin Ouh sorry.. See my updated answer

Comment: When I edited the script the dialog content is appeared on the page and the dialog is not showing

Comment: This is the code 

`  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog2" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      show: {
        
        duration: 150
      },
      hide: {
        
        duration: 500
      }
    });
    $( "#opener2" ).click(function() {
      $( "#dialog2" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
  });`

Comment: Could you show me in jsfiddle ? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/G8RQS/

That's it

Comment: Okay @KevinMartin ,  check my final updated answer